# Looking for a better way to extend methods

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, extensibility

I'm working on a hobby project in Unity. I have `MonoBehaviour` scripts for my characters that use component objects for each behavior the character has. When I create new characters, I inherit a new class from the base class for whichever component behaves differently.

When certain triggers occur, I send characters back to their initial state by calling a `Reset()` method exposed by the base class that sets fields back to their initial values. I'm wondering how to send that call down through the inheritance chain. Right now, the base class has a protected virtual `ChildReset()` that gets called in `Reset()` and does nothing by default. If child classes have fields to reset, they override this method. It feels like a really awkward way of doing it.

I like the idea of implementing something similar to the [messaging system](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SendMessage.html) Unity uses. If a monobehavior doesn't use the `Update()` message, then the class just doesn't define an update. It eliminates unnecessary calls. I have no idea how I would do something like that.

Any thought invested in this is much appreciated! I've written out the way my project is structured below just in case these details are useful for answers.

```
public class Character : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Motion motionController;
    private Interaction characterInteractionController;
    //etc

    private void Update()
    {
        motionController.DoStuff();
        characterInteractionController.DoStuff();
    }

    private void Reset()
    {
        motionController.Reset();
        characterInteractionController.Reset();
    }

    private void OnEnable() => ResetTrigger.OnReset += Reset;
    private void OnDisable() => ResetTrigger.OnReset -= Reset;
}

public class Motion : Component {}
public class Interaction : Component {}

public abstract class Component
{
    public void Reset() 
    { 
        /* set fields to default values */ 
        ChildReset();
    }
    
    protected virtual void ChildReset() { }
    public abstract void DoStuff();
}
```

Comment: Be careful with the method name! [`Reset`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Reset.html) already is a special method name which is invoked by Unity everytime you use `AddComponent` in the Inspector or reset from the component context menu! You would get exceptions since the class fields might not be initialized in those cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to send a call down through the inheritance chain. You do not have two different objects. An object of the child class contains everything declared in the base class. Why not directly make `Reset()` virtual?

```cs
public abstract class Character : MonoBehaviour
{
    public virtual void Reset()
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class ChildCharacter : Character
{
    // If ChildCharacter has stuff to reset, override this method, otherwise don't!
    public override void Reset()
    {
        base.Reset(); // Call this to reset stuff from the base class.

        //TODO: reset child stuff.
    }
}
```

If `Reset` is overridden in the child class, then calling `Reset` will call `ChildCharacter.Reset()` even if called on a variable statically typed as `Character`.

```cs
    Character c = new ChildCharacter();
    c.Reset(); // calls ChildCharacter.Reset() when overridden
```

If `Reset` is not overridden in the child class, then calling `Reset` will call `Character.Reset()` even if called on a `ChildCharacter`.

```cs
    ChildCharacter child = new ChildCharacter();
    child.Reset(); // calls Character.Reset() when not overridden.
```

Comment: That's definitely something I overlooked by overthinking things. How can I be sure that anyone who overrides Reset() will remember to call base.Reset()?

Comment: See [Generate an override in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/generate-override?view=vs-2022). Visual Studio does this for you, but there is no guarantee. It is just a good practice to call the base implementation in an override.

Comment: I don't want to rely on good practice to make my project function properly, and that was a red flag that my question was motivated by a design flaw. The new fields and behavior I was adding in child classes were unrelated to the purpose of the base class. It's a case where composition should be used instead of inheritance.

Comment: Thank you for helping! I don't know if other people can gain anything from my question as is. Would you recommend that I delete this question, or should I modify the question and/or post an answer that details my design changes in order to help others who may have misused inheritance?

Comment: This is how inheritance is done. Calling an abstract or virtual method as you did (`ChildReset`) is also a common practice. Modifying your question would invalidate my answer. Keep it as is.